# How many permutations of 7 digits, 4 digits the same, & 3 different from the 4 but also the same

Tags: probability

In other words, how many permutations are available for 4A3B, e.g., 3333999, 3939339.

I guess this could be restated as how many permutations are available from X digits, with Y the same, and Z the same but where Y<>Z. But really I can do the generalization. I'm having a hard time visualizing this. I'm more interesting in thought process than the actual answer.

I'm assuming permutations like 0000111 are included in the count.

Comment: Could you consider clarifying the question?

Comment: let’s pretend we have a combination 3334444. This has 3 digits that are the same and 4 that are the same. Total 7 digits. You can produce 35 permutations of this, for example 4343344 is one. What are the total possibilities of all such 3A4B (e.g., 0001111) permutations for all 0-9 digits. (4+3)!/(4!3!) = 35 but that only covers one possiblity.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea:  There are $(Y+Z)!$ permutations of the digits.  However $Y!$ and $Z!$ are the same arrangements for each digit respectively, so the net result is $\frac{(Y+Z)!}{Y!Z!}$

Comment: I may have been unclear, but that’s not what I’m asking. I believe your answer gives me how many possibilities for a given selection within the 3A4B  or XAYB grouping. What I’m asking for is all possibilities across all selections within the 3A3B or XAYB groupings. I tried 10x2x2x2x2x2x2 but that gets me close but I’m missing something. I think I’m double counting.

Comment: The answer I gave you is the total number of different possibilities.  Are you asking for the number of arrangements where all look the same?  That would be $Y!Z!$.  You need to clarify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are ${10\choose 1}$ ways to choose the first category of digits, then there are ${9\choose 1}$ ways to choose the second category of digits. Finally, there are $\frac{7!}{4!\cdot 3!}$ ways to permute the digits:
$${10\choose 1}{9\choose 1}\frac{7!}{4!\cdot 3!}.$$

In general, for the $X$-digit number with $Y$ the same and $Z$ the same, but $Y\ne Z$:
$${10\choose 1}{9\choose 1}\cdot \frac{X!}{Y!Z!}.$$